# How can I replace a specific character on a label

Tags: vb.net

**Idea:**

I simply want to replace the `"-"`symbol for a `"•"` symbol on a label for grapic proposes.

I've tried the below code but the program is not compiling this piece of code, or actually isn't loading up the whole class:

```
Dim _plate As New lblplate.text
With _plate
    Replace(_plate, "-", "•")
End With
```

Comment: Replace is a function.  You aren't using the results.  Remove the With block — you aren't using it.

Comment: lblplate.Text = lblplate.Text.Replace(etc...)

Comment: I'm guessing "didnt work" means it does not compile?  `Dim _plate As New lblplate.text` should fail because `lblplate.text` is not a type.

Comment: It actually compiles but it wasn't changing anything, with @pallares 's response it worked with no problems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```
lblplate.Text = lblplate.Text.Replace("-", "•")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't new I could use the object directly to replace the value on it, Good to know!